# Directx11 create Texture2D using subresourceData

Tags: c++, textures, directx11

I'm trying to create immutable texture in d3d11 so I want to use subresourceData, every tutorial on textures creates them with 2nd argument being null and after that updates subresource but I want to create it using the 2nd argument. 
This code works:

```
hResult = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &m_cubeTexture);
if (FAILED(hResult)) {
    return false;
}

int rowPitch = textureWidth * 4;
m_deviceContext->UpdateSubresource(m_cubeTexture, 0, NULL, &(decodedTexture[0]), rowPitch, rowPitch * textureHeight);
```

And this does not:

```
int rowPitch = textureWidth * 4;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA tSData;
tSData.pSysMem = &(decodedTexture[0]);
tSData.SysMemPitch = rowPitch;
tSData.SysMemSlicePitch = rowPitch * textureHeight;

hResult = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, &tSData, &m_cubeTexture);
if (FAILED(hResult)) {
    return false;
}
```

DirectX11 debug layer outputs this:

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: pInitialData[3].SysMemPitch cannot be 0 [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #100: CREATETEXTURE2D_INVALIDINITIALDATA]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: pInitialData[5].pSysMem cannot be NULL. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #100: CREATETEXTURE2D_INVALIDINITIALDATA]
```

Which I don't understand since it's not even an array and texture array size is set to 1

Comment: If it's not an array texture then you must have miplevels specified (each miplevel is also a subresource).  What is the value of textureDesc.MipLevels?  Anything other than 1 will cause this.

Comment: For [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/DDSTextureLoader.cpp) and [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/WICTextureLoader.cpp) in the _DirectX Tool Kit_ I use ``initData`` initialization. The source code for these should help.

Comment: This thread has the answer: https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/599837-dx11-createtexture2d-automatic-mips-initial-data/

Answer (score 1):

When you create texture as D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE set MipLevels to 1.

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc= {};
textureDesc.Width= textureWidth;
textureDesc.Height= textureHeight;
textureDesc.MipLevels= 1; /// !!!
textureDesc.ArraySize= 1;
textureDesc.Format= DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count= 1;
textureDesc.Usage= D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
textureDesc.BindFlags= D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags= 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags= 0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA tSData= {};
tSData.pSysMem = &(decodedTexture[0]);
tSData.SysMemPitch = rowPitch;
tSData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

hResult= m_device->CreateTexture2D( &textureDesc, &tSData, &m_cubeTexture);
```

Have in mind that if you create D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE texture like this, you won't be able to call GenerateMips on it.